# When a Bluetooth audio device auto-connects volume settings won't work until I manually select it

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, volume-control

I have an Asus UX32VD running 12.10 and for audio I'm using a Big Jambox. They're paired and connect quickly every time. It also correctly directs audio to the Jambox every time it connects.

The problem is that when the Jambox connects the volume keys and volume control indicator applet don't work. When I open the volume control app after the Jambox connects it is unselected (despite playing the audio already). Once I select it then the volume control works as it should.

This wouldn't be a problem were it for but one thing - it defaults to max volume. Which is a problem with a Big Jambox.

So the question is how do I get the volume control app to accurately reflect what the system is already doing?

Answer (score 5):

You could add **load-module module-switch-on-connect** to your file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

On my Ubuntu 12.04 system, I added this line before the lines that set the volume restore:

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
```

When this takes effect, (`pulseaudio -k` to restart), I can connect to a bluetooth audio sink, and the audio stream switches to the right output and the volume keys directly trigger on the bluetooth sink.